# Why are uintXX_t's not C++ keywords?

Tags: c++, std

While developing a C++ application, I felt it was cumbersome to write *#include < inttypes.h >* at the top of each of the header files. Then I was suddenly curious about why *uintXX_t* types are not just reserved as keywords, even if they are parts of the standard. I think they could have been provided as built-in types. What made the standard committee leave them in a separate header file?

Comment: Are you asking why it was added as regular code to be parsed by the existing compiler, rather than built into the compiler itself (made a built-in type)? I think it makes sense, the implementation is simpler this way.

Comment: One obvious reason is that not all platforms are capable of supporting them.  Think uint8_t on a platform where CHAR_BIT is 32.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yeap that's what I meant. I revised the question to use the term 'built-in' for clarity.

Comment: fyi: Wrong header `<cstdint>` is the correct one `< inttypes.h >` is deprecated: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header  As to your question: the types are all annotated with _"provided only if the implementation directly supports the type"_

Comment: @RichardCritten I believe you meant `<cinttypes>`. Of course, both declare the types, but `<cstdint>` is not the corresponding header to `<inttypes.h>`. Follow up question: How does implementing fixed width integer types as aliases (i.e. defining them in a header) follow from the conditional providing of the type?

Comment: @user2079303 Was looking where the declarations were actually defined my mistake, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint

Comment: @user2079303 Re follow up question: on platforms where the types are not supported just supply a custom header file without the typedefs.  Think about GCC and the many platforms it supports, changing a header file is less risky than removing built-in types from the compilers source code. It could even be done with `#ifdef`(s) for the supported platforms therefore not needing any customisation at all.

Comment: Becasue it would break a lot of existing code, including all the implementations that already provided it as a typedef. Because that's not what new keywords are really for.

Comment: @RichardCritten -- while it's true that `<inttypes.h>` is deprecated, so are all the rest of the standard C headers. And although they have been since 1998, everybody uses them. The fact that they are deprecated is simply irrelevant to coding decisions. Granted, there are arguable reasons for not using the C headers, but deprecation is not one of them.

Comment: @PeteBecker My thinking is: if irrelevant as you say, why has the standards body marked the headers as deprecated?  Either there is an intention to remove these headers from future versions of the standard  and new code should not use them. Or there is no intention to remove the headers from the standard and therefore the use of deprecated should to be raised as a defect in the current standard.

Comment: @RichardCritten -- as a practical matter, the C headers will not be removed. Deprecating them was wrongheaded; back then some folks even naively thought that C++ compilers would re-implement the C library on top of the C++ library. Formally, that deprecation is not a defect: deprecation is not a promise that something **will be** removed, but a warning that something **might** be removed. But it's never going to happen.